# Plotting table in python (matplotlib alternatives)

Tags: python, plot, table-display

Are there any alternatives to `matplotlib` as it comes to plotting tables?

I find it very inconvenient to plot tables in matplotlib. It's hard to make small change of one parameter - table size (scale), font size, cells contents, column widths/heights etc. often requires fine-tuning all other parameters.

Comment: @eshirvana I did and not found anything, finding "alternatives to matplotlib table" gives me matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some alternatives. One of them that you might want to look at is `Plotly`. Have a look at its documentation and examples showing how to plot interactive tables.
https://plotly.com/python/table/

Comment: Thank you. Have you used this and can recommend it? Is it better, easier to use than matplolib?

Comment: I have been using it for quite often. It is now one of the strongest visualization libraries in the perspective of binding `backend` Python code and visualize the result immediately.

> Is it better, easier to use than matplolib?
We cannot say something is better than the other as each person has his/her own personality. Plotly, however, does provide ways for you to create `interactive` tables (and other types of charts) and is indeed easy to use (easy for people who dive into its doc and try to understand how to use it).

Comment: Yes, it is great, I used it too (didn't know it has tables) - but have you used it for displaying tables?

Comment: Yes, I use it quite often both to plot tables and others as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Hoang, I'll wait for some days, and if no one gives better answer will accept this one.